# Python importing messages module not working

Tags: python

I am trying to parse some protobuf messages and importing the `messages` module. However getting below error. Not sure what I am missing.
Please advise.

```
>>> import messages
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/messages/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .api import send
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/messages/api.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .email_ import Email
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/messages/email_.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ._config import check_config_file
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/messages/_config.py", line 12, in <module>
    import jsonconfig
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/jsonconfig/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .core import Config
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/jsonconfig/core.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .jsonutils import to_json_file, from_json_file
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/jsonconfig/jsonutils.py", line 29, in <module>
    to_json = box._to_json
AttributeError: module 'box' has no attribute '_to_json'
```

Comment: Seems `jsonconfig.jsonutils` is broken, not `messages`

Comment: If you have protobuf schemas, shouldnt you have some `<record>_pb2.py` file that you should be importing with the compiled class?

Comment: Well, I am only trying `import messages` in python console and it is failing. Protobuf is a different thing.

Comment: I uninstall both messages and jsonconfig and installed again. Same issue.

Comment: `messages` has dependency on `jsonconfig-tools` that seems to be broken.

Comment: I suggest opening an issue, then https://github.com/trp07/messages

Comment: Done. https://github.com/trp07/messages/issues/27

Comment: There is a fix available here,
https://github.com/json-transformations/jsonconfig/pull/219/files